# boolean when true is selected bring back both true and false values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a query which has a field that brings back 1's and 0's.  I want to use a Boolean parameter in my report...which when true is selected brings back all the 1's **and** 0's and when false is selected just brings back the 0's.

Currently when true is selected it just brings back 1's which is what you would suspect but is there a way to pull the 0's through as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WHERE clause should look like

```
WHERE ( FieldName = @Param OR @Param = 1)
```